# How to get blob URL while a Stram a video from Azure Blob storage

Tags: url, video-streaming, blob, urlencode, azure-storage-account

I have a container and a blob of mp4 type in my Azure storage account.
I am **able to stream it from the Blob.Uri (or using SAS token if required) in HTML5 video control**.

But I need to convert that Blob Uri to be converted as "blob:" url so copying the source from developer's tool will not play the video in any new window.

I don't want to download the full video first anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

I am showing/streaming the video like:

```
List<string> blobPaths = new List<string>();

foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true))
{

    if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blb = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
        string sasToken = blb.GetSharedAccessSignature(null, "spolicy");
        blobPaths.Add(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}", blb.Uri, sasToken));
     }
 }
 ViewBag.Path1 = blobPaths[0];
```

Main point is that I want Netflix type of feature, **so that copying the video source from web page's view source won't work.**
Also *video should not be downloaded locally.*

Comment: is it c#? better put it in the tag and use \```c# \``` to wrap your code instead of ```

Comment: Yes this is in **c#**

But here, my code is not much important..Rather I need some way how to convert URL.CreateObjectUrl() of video being stremed from blob storage account in azure